# Android selector with background image and gradient

Tags: android, button, background

I know there are similar post to this but I couldn't find my answer in any of them. So, I have this drawable XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_enabled="true">
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/bm_btn_background"
        android:tileMode="repeat"
        android:gravity="center" />
</item>
<item android:state_enabled="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#a0e0b071"
            android:endColor="#a0a67637"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#5c3708" />
        <corners
            android:radius="5dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#a0a67637"
            android:endColor="#a0e0b071"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#5c3708" />
        <corners
            android:radius="5dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

I am trying to create a button with a repeated image as background and a gradient applied to it. With this code I only see the background image, not the gradient nor the border and the rounded corners. Also, when I click the button, it doesn't change (the gradient is supposed to change). I don't know what is wrong with this code? If instead of a selector I use a layer-list, I get the desired result but it doesn't change either when I press the button. Thanks for your help!

Comment: are you setting the file as a background to the Button or not?

Comment: Yes: android:background="@drawable/button"

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Your code for the selector is wrong because:

- You have two elements for the same state and as the selector encounters the first state(`state_enabled`) for the `Bitmap` element it will stop there and your gradient will never appear(for this you should use a `layer-list` that has as items the `Bitmap` and the gradient on top)
- The selector will match states in order. As you press the `Button` the `state_pressed` will never be activated because the selector will match first the `state_enabled` that is on the first element(for this you should move the code for the `state_pressed` above the state_enabled elements).

In fact you should just remove the `state_enabled` and let the `Bitmap` + `gradient` be the default value for the `Button`. Bellow is your selector(I assumed you only want to change gradient on the image(but the image should appear even in the pressed state, if this isn't the wanted behavior leave only the gradient for the `state_pressed`)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bm_btn_background" android:tileMode="repeat" />
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape>
                     <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#a0e0b071" android:startColor="#a0a67637" />
                     <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#5c3708" />
                     <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                     <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item android:state_enabled="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bm_btn_background" android:tileMode="repeat" />
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#a0a67637" android:startColor="#a0e0b071" />
                    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#5c3708" />
                    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>


</selector>
```

Comment: Now I understand how states are interpreted. Thanks. This works! Thanks to everybody1

Comment: One little problem. The rounded corners are not applied to the background, only to the shape.

Comment: @ali The `layer-list` doesn't modify the items in it, it will simply stack the items one on top of the other, so your `Bitmap` will be used as it is. Your free to search but I don't know a way to do it in the xml drawable, your best bet you'll probably be to round the image yourself.

Comment: @gabby Please start a new question providing details about your current setup.

Comment: @Luksprog: Thanks a lot. Was trying to find something like `<layer-list>`. 
Your code helped me a lot.

Comment: @user also have a look at my question plz https://stackoverflow.com/q/72644805/4134215

Answer (score 0):

in my case i am using this. try it

```
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/mediumGray" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1px"
            android:color="@color/darkGray" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="2dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="2dp" />

        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="7sp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="7sp"
            android:topLeftRadius="7sp"
            android:topRightRadius="7sp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/mediumGray" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1px"
            android:color="@color/darkGray" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="2dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="2dp" />

        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="7sp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="7sp"
            android:topLeftRadius="7sp"
            android:topRightRadius="7sp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/lightGray" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1px"
            android:color="@color/blackTransparent" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="2dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="2dp" />

        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="7sp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="7sp"
            android:topLeftRadius="7sp"
            android:topRightRadius="7sp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on your  state attrubute

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/nicebuttonround" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/nicebuttonround" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/nicebuttonroundi" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/nicebuttonroundi" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/nicebuttonroundi" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/nice22i" android:state_pressed="true"/>

</selector>
```

For repeating background as image you just have to create 9 pitch images.

Comment: You meant `nine-patch`.

Answer (score 0):

I have added extra transperent space to the right side of image using photoshop canvas size option and it works fine for me. download below image to see demo. 
[image]