# The only image for all button states for Android?

Tags: android, button, android-imagebutton, visualstates

I have an image for my button.
In order to make use of it I have to have 1 additional image for each state:
1. disabled
2. selected
3. pressed
etc..

in iOS all those additional states are handled automatically and deferred from original image provided.

Is it possible to accomplish this for Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to accomplish this for Android?

**No, It is NOT**.  You need to have all states's images with you to define the *selector*

You can define button_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <!-- Selected state -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>

    <!-- Pressed  state -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>

     <!-- Disabled   state -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"></item>

    <!-- Normal state -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_normal"></item>



</selector>
```

Then simply assign this selector as a `background` of a button

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
     android:layout_width="200dp"
     android:layout_height="126dp"
     android:text="Hello" />
```

Refer : [Button Selector](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

Hope it will help you ツ

Comment: in this scenario I have to have 3 different images (1 for each state supported)

Comment: yes.. you must have IMAGES for all states you wanna support

Comment: and I don't want to :) for iOS I can have the only and then OS will invert, add gradients, etc to provide visual feedback on user actions

Comment: It is **NOT** possible in adnroid

Comment: Just [have a look once](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10449796/2591002) if it helps you

Comment: is there a way to generate set of assets base on one input image?

Answer (score 0):

**This answer refers to how you can handle button states in Android**
You can create a button layout file separately in put that in `res > layout` folder

For Instance:

if the layout file name is `btn.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" />   
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal"/> 

</selector>
```

You can set `BackgroundResource` of a `Button`

```
yourButton.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.btn);
```

**EDIT**

In addition you can refer to this [link](http://shiki.me/blog/android-button-background-image-pressedhighlighted-and-disabled-states-without-using-multiple-images/) which is more closer to answer your question

Comment: in this scenario I have to have 2(3) different images (1 for each state supported)

Comment: yes, one image will be shown as normal and one when the button will be pressed

Comment: but I have the only image (topic)

Comment: Answer refers to how you can handle button states in Android

Comment: and I asked another question - how to deal with the only image

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use selector for android.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/focused"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>

 android:background="@drawable/selector_button" />
```

just [have a look of this link.](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2014/03/android-button-selector-tutorial-with.html#.VGry2NSSw8o)

Comment: in your scenario I still have to have 3 different images (1 for each state supported)

Answer (score 0):

For selected and pressed you can use an xml file with  root for button's background but for disabled I guess you need to handle it in java code. I'm not sure about disabled state.

Comment: could you show an example with "xml file with root button's background"

Comment: other users have already given you that xml file in their answers, if you are worried about making images you can use Android Asset Studio(google it and select first result) to produce suitable images fast and easy.

Comment: Oh yes, if there a online tool that would be helpful. Here http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio I couldn't see any button states images generator

Comment: If my answer helped you please mark it as resolved and vote up, thanks

Comment: use this tool:http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html plus tht xml with <Selector> as other peopl have mentioned in their answers to implement what you want.

Comment: thank you for the link but it is still not clear: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oe4q6459nq0gjkq/Screenshot%202014-11-18%2012.21.25.png?dl=0 how to get grayed icon for disabled state for example?

Comment: Maybe use color and set it's opacity to 100% ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you need to handle this states in a new resource file called cursor: e.g:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/edittext_selector" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <!-- Image display in background in select state -->
    <item
       android:state_pressed="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/edittextback1">
    </item>

    <!-- Image display in background in select state -->
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/edittextback2">
    </item>

    <!-- Default state -->
    <!--<item android:state_enabled="true"-->
        <!--android:drawable="@drawable/your_ninepath_image">-->
    <!--</item>-->
</selector>
```

Comment: but here all the state displays the same image and no visual effects for press/disabled states will be applied

Comment: It's only an example, the image will be de drawable that you will use depending on which state you have. I will edit it so we avoid misunderstandings

Comment: in this scenario I have to have 3 different images (1 for each state supported) and I have the only image

Comment: You will need different images as I said before, as far as I know. I think that you need different images to achieve the effect of change depending on the state.